# How can I use regex to match both single word strings and hyphenated strings?

Tags: regex, string, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind

I am trying to match the first word after a specific string using regex and have been struggling to make all instances work properly. Let's say I have 2 strings:

`Site Code: foobar`

`Site Code: hello-world`

Now, using `(?<=\bSite Code:\s)(\w+)` returns `foobar` which is correct, but only returns `hello` when I need `hello-world` instead.

So, I changed my expression to `(?<=\bSite Code:\s)(\w+)(-\w+)` in order to pickup the hyphenated words, but now it is ignoring the non-hyphenated words.

Is there a way to get both `foobar` and `hello-world` from the same expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=\bSite Code:\s)([-\w]+)

#\w only include the range [A-Za-z0-9_] in ascii mode.
```

Comment: Oh I will, just have to wait 5 more minutes before the system allows me to... You were too quick for your own good lol

Answer (score 2):

Try this `(?<=\bSite Code:\s)(\S+)`

Without more detail on the requirements it's hard to give an exact answer.
The above regex should match all non-whitespace characters after the specific string "Site Code: ".

Comment: edi_allen's answer above will only match words with a hyphen but will ignore other symbols such as +,@, etc...

Comment: Ah, I was just about to ask what the difference was. I may need to ignore those symbols anyway, specifically `.`, as the values are being converted into urls. I left that out of my question though. +1 for a good answer though. Thanks!